# Turn multidimensional array into associative multidimentional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I'm having an array like this

```
$myArray = [
   [
       'key1' => $val1,
       'key2' => $val2,
       'key3' => $val3,
   ],
   [
       'key1' => $val4,
       'key2' => $val5,
       'key3' => $val6,
   ],
];
```

I want to convert `$myArray` into an assocciative array like this

```
$myArray = [
   $val3 => [
       'key1' => $val1,
       'key2' => $val2,
       'key3' => $val3,
   ],
   $val6 =>[
       'key1' => $val4,
       'key2' => $val5,
       'key3' => $val6,
   ],
];
```

Is there a php function or a combination of functions that does this for you?

Comment: What is `$val3` and `$val6` ? you mean the last key of each array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One-liner, for better understanding in several lines:

```
print_r(
    array_combine(
        array_column($myArray, 'key3'),
        $myArray
    )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe like this ?

```
function conv_arr($arr) {
    $newArr = [];
    foreach ($arr as $r) {
        $newArr[end($r)] = $r;
    }
    return $newArr;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get a new `array` with the last `key` of each array, try this:

```
<?php
$new = array();
$myArray = [
   [
       'key1' => 1,
       'key2' => 2,
       'key3' => 3,
   ],
   [
       'key1' => 4,
       'key2' => 5,
       'key3' => 6,
   ],
];

foreach( $myArray as $array ){
    end($array);
    $key = key($array);
    $new[$array[$key]] = $array;
}

print_r($new);
```

Using `foreach` only.

Answer (score 0):

If your example output is illustrative of the pattern you intend to use, then you may use this example as a guide. See comments for a step-by-step explanation.

```
<?php

// Your variables defined.
$val1 = 1;
$val2 = 2;
$val3 = 3;
$val4 = 4;
$val5 = 5;
$val6 = 6;

// Your input array.
$myArray = [
   [
       'key1' => $val1,
       'key2' => $val2,
       'key3' => $val3,
   ],
   [
       'key1' => $val4,
       'key2' => $val5,
       'key3' => $val6,
   ],
];

$result = [];
// Loop over each element of your input array
foreach ($myArray as $el)
    // Use the value of the last element of each child array as the index to the child.
    $result[end($el)] = $el;

var_dump($result);
```

Output:

```
/*
array(2) {
  [3]=>
  array(3) {
    ["key1"]=>
    int(1)
    ["key2"]=>
    int(2)
    ["key3"]=>
    int(3)
  }
  [6]=>
  array(3) {
    ["key1"]=>
    int(4)
    ["key2"]=>
    int(5)
    ["key3"]=>
    int(6)
  }
}
*/
```